# Ошибка при работе с SOAP из Delphi

Tags: delphi, soap, https

Помогите с SOAP. Есть SOAP сервис вот он: https://ca.gov.am:8080/SAPIWS/dss.asmx
С паленым сертификатом, к которому необходимо подключиться из делфи, но при генерации WSDL importer выдает ошибку сертификата, но позволяет продолжить, при этом после нажатой кнопки YES выдает ошибку

> Unable load WSDL ... Error [Empti document]

Как можно это обойти?

P.S. При подключеню к сервису из .NET таких проблем не возникает, т.е. сервис в принципе работающий, проблема - в сертификате и ограничениях делфей.

Версия делфи 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скачайте и подсуньте локально ему wsdl. Возможно это решит вашу проблему.

P.S.: Я делал так в php, но с другой целью: экономить на трафике; почему-то .NET программисты полагают, что все сервисы - у них трафик неограниченный и скорость как у бога, поэтому делают wsdl файлы весом от 1 и выше мб. Сервис-то может и откликается быстро, но вот шаблон то грузится долго!!! Так что копируйте к себе его.

Comment: Попробовал так тоже ,
Но уже при обращении к серверу выдает ошибку.